# How to prevent background image from being cut off during printing

Tags: html, css

I am making a multi-page menu for my family-owned restaurant, and I am having trouble with printing.
Whenever I go to print the menu, it always shows the top being cut off even though it fills the screen normally.

I've tried to change the `html` to `body` down below(causing the same result), and I already tried changing the size of the image(ending up duplicating the image more frequently than one image per page, leaving it cut off, or both)

The following is the CSS code that I am using (The URL is revised though):

```css
html {
        background-image: url("example.com/bgimage.jpg");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

I am using the `repeat-y` to Make one image per page

I expected that typing more might fix the problem (or keep it the same) but it just makes more and more of the background cut off.

Comment: For one page of full text, about 5/8 of the image is left

Comment: The actual printing is fine, so ignore this and dislike if you want, but it would also help knowing why the preview was like that

Comment: Could you please provide a link?

Comment: I cannot provide a link, sorry

Comment: I am not experienced enough to go past a custom domain, so that means making a whole custom URL would be a problem and my domain is private information and not serchable